# react-webcam-barcode-scanner not working when configuring in production server

Tags: reactjs, barcode

I have been working with a project which uses react-webcam-barcode-scanner as a package for reading barcode using laptop's webcam. It works fine in my development server which is localhost but when I deploy it to the production server, the scanner can't initialize and access the webcam. Is there any solution for the problem in hand ?

Answer (score 0):

if it works on localhost, you should try with "https" scheme on the other side.